# How would I use regular expression to match a word with at least 5 characters with 's' as the last one?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regex to match: a word that's at least 5 characters long and ends with an 's', but the 's' is included in the 5 characters. Say for example, I have the following words:

```
hexes pixies major prairies caveman zipfiles oxes
```

I tried doing `([a-z]s?){5,}`

Comment: At least 5 characters long, ending on s like this? `\b[a-z]{4,}s\b` https://regex101.com/r/PCYduR/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `([a-z]s?){5,}` repeats 5 or more times a character in the range a-z followed by an optional `s` char

If you only want to match characters a-z and "words" are determined by word boundaries `\b`, you can match 4 or more times the range a-z and end the match with an `s` char

```
\b[a-z]{4,}s\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PCYduR)

Answer (score 1):

To add to **The fourth bird**'s answer: if you also want to match for capital letters, add **A-Z** like this:

```
\b[A-Za-z]{4,}s\b
```

You can also match for special alphabetical characters like (æøåäöüß...) with **À-ȕ**, like this:

```
\b[A-Za-zÀ-ȕ]{4,}s\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/55RXxG/1)